# Sendmail not starting on port 2525 on google cloud vm instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to use sendmail on port 2525 to send mails from google cloud vm instance. I have created firewall rules in project settings and also in the VM instance. But sendmail is not starting and the command is hanging. Port 2525 is in SYN_SENT state. Please assist to resolve. Posted sendmail.mc below. Also please find the changes I have done so far in trying to successfully send outbound mail from the VM instance. dnl entries are the default format of sendmail.mc file.

i) Create egress rule to allow ports 1024-65535
ii) Create ingress rule to allow ports 1024-65535
iii) Update /etc/services files to point smtp to 2525
iv) Update iptables to allow ports 1024-65535 for inbound and outbound connection
v) Updated relay server in sendmail.mc to smtp.gmail.com

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl
dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.gmail.com')dnl
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl
dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl
dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
dnl define(`confINET_QOS', `AF11')dnl
dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl
dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

Comment: Where have you configured port 2525? Edit your question with more details. Also, your configuration file looks very strange with the **dnl** everywhere. Replace with the actual file contents.

Comment: Hello John, Updated the question with more details, as to what i have tried so far. dnl is created by default from sendmail package as syntax for sendmail.mc. Please let me know if you want more outputs to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> use sendmail on port 2525 to send mails from google cloud vm instance.

Changing Sendmail's source port won't help...

[All outgoing connections  to port 25 are blocked](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) on Google Compute. And almost all mailservers will only accept incoming SMTP traffic and e-mail on the default SMTP port, TCP port 25.

Comment: Hi, yes I have updated the /etc/services file to point smtp to 2525. So whenever i start the sendmail, it starts communicating via port 2525. But the port state moves to SYN_SENT(which from my search seems the port is waiting for reply from destination). I tried the following changes to accomplish. i) Create egress rule to allow ports 1024-65535 ii) Create ingress rule to allow ports 1024-65535 iii) Update /etc/services files to point smtp to 2525 iv) Update iptables to allow ports 1024-65535 for inbound and outbound connection v) Updated relay server in sendmail.mc to smtp.gmail.com